# Guice multibindings package missing in imports

Tags: java, maven, guice, ivy

I have acquired the google.inject package via ivy in my IDE, however, I dont see the pacakage

```
com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder
```

Which is referenced here

http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/Multibinder.html

I'm wondering --- maybe there are multiple guice repost which I should pull from ?

**I do, however, see the following packages : com.google.inject -> binder/internal/matcher/util**

My ivy definition :

```
 <dependency org="com.google.inject" name="guice" rev="3.0" conf="*->*,!javadoc"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in the "guice-multibindings" artifact.

```
<dependency org="com.google.inject.extensions" name="guice-multibindings" rev="3.0"/>
```

[mvnrepository info](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-multibindings/3.0)

(FWIW, sometimes info like this is easy to discover by downloading a project's main artifact(s) and un-archiving it, I just looked at the version I had laying around and saw the jar file then searched on mvnrepository for "guice", and there it was.)