# Inject multiple interface implementations into class constructor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm new with Java Guice, and I have trouble with designing my application.
I'll try to explain my design and the desired result as simple as I can.
I have an interface called `Ialgorithm`, and 3 implementations of that interface, lets say `IalgorithmA`,`IalgorithmB`,`IalgirthmC`.
I have a class called `myClass` with the following constructor:

```
public myClass(Ialgorithm alg) {...}
```

Now I want to be able to inject an instance of one of the implementations of the `Ialgorithm` interface, using annotations:
I want at the end to be able to write in my main:

```
// ... intialize an Injector with a Moudle that extents AbstractModule
myClass a = injecotr.getInstance(key.get(myClass.class,Aannotation.class));
myClass b = injecotr.getInstance(key.get(myClass.class,Bannotation.class));
myClass c = injecotr.getInstance(key.get(myClass.class,Cannotation.class));
```

I read a few tutorials in the web, but I couldn't find exact way to achieve this.

In addition, and after the above issue will be solved, I extend my question:
Actually, The third implementation, `IalgirthmC`, is different from the two other implementations which contain a default constructor: its constructor is:

```
public IalgorithmC(Ialgorithm,int n) {...}
```

Now it becomes more complicated... because I want the Guice to inject the Ialgorithm parameter, but the int parameter shouldn't injected by the Guice (@Assisted), and this whole instance of `IalgorithmC` should be injected into `myClass` when using the `Cannotaion`. 
Of course that I should provide a value for the int parameter and an annotation to the internal `Ialgorithm` in `IalgorithmC`.

Thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046805/guice-and-interface-that-has-multiple-implementations) talk about one solution for multiple implementations in guice.