# Guice: inject different implementation depending on who is getting it?

Tags: java, guice

I have two third-party classes, both of which take an implementation of an `Authorizer` interface. I need to inject each with a different implementation.

If I do an `@Provides`, how can I implement it so that it provides the implementation required at run time? The provider has no idea who is asking for the injection.

In theory I could use `@Named`, but I can't modify the code being injected. I want to do something like:

```
bind(Authorizer.class).to(ImplA.class).for(SomeClass.class)
bind(Authorizer.class).to(ImplB.class).for(SomeOtherClass.class)
```

Obviously, the "for" code doesn't exist, but is there some equivalent way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046805/guice-and-interface-that-has-multiple-implementations

Comment: `@Named` and other binding annotations are the way you're supposed to deal with this.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of those solutions require annotating the code being injected which I, as I mentioned, I can't do (they're from 3rd party jars).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Private Modules](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html), which let you install (mutually-inaccessible) conflicting bindings to be used in constructing a limited set of non-conflicting *exposed* bindings. This is often seen as a solution to the [robot legs problem](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects), in which you'd want to (for instance) expose a `@Left Leg` and a `@Right Leg` where the `Leg` object is exactly the same but you've bound different `Foot` implementations (`LeftFoot` and `RightFoot`) further down in the hierarchy.

At this point, you're not specifying "who is getting it", but you're exposing a slightly different Injector graph for one consumer versus the other.

```
install(new PrivateModule() {
  bind(Authorizer.class).to(ImplA.class);
  expose(SomeClass.class);
});
install(new PrivateModule() {
  bind(Authorizer.class).to(ImplB.class);
  expose(SomeOtherClass.class);
});
```