# Inject the same class with different parameters with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have 2 different classes(Cart and Payment) trying to use same database accessor class DBAccessor, as DBAccessor only contains logic to read and write data from a DB in a fixed format.

```
public class Cart{
    @Inject
    Cart(@Cart DBService db){
    }
..
}

public class Payment{
    @Inject
    Payment(@Payment DBService db){
    }
..
}

public class CartDBService implements DBService{
    @Inject
    public CartDBService(DBAccessor){
    }
}
public class PaymentDBService implements DBService{
    @Inject
    public PaymentDBService(DBAccessor){
    }
}
public class DBAccessor{
    @Inject
    public DBAccessor(String tableName){
    }
}
```

I want to inject dependencies using guice in the give setup making sure everything is created by guice.

I am using binding annotation to inject different DBService instances for Cart and Payment.

```
bind(DBService.class).annotatedWith(Cart.class).to(CartDBService.class);
bind(DBService.class).annotatedWith(Payment.class).to(PaymentDBService.class);
```

How do I inject separate DBAccessor classes for cart and order to make sure they get correct table names injected.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate: This is known as the "robot legs" problem, as if you were injecting a `@Left Leg` and `@Right Leg` with identical knees and ankles but separate feet. This way, your DBAccessor can be different for `@Cart` and `@Payment` services no matter how many times you inject them, or how deeply into the graph you inject them. See: ["Guice: inject different implementation depending on who is getting it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36186724/1426891) and [How to implement the “robot legs” use case with Google Guice?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35784112/1426891).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the design: class `DBAccessor` is doing too much work since it's reading different kind of data from different tables, now Guice is saving you by showing you that you were a bad boy...

Solution: implement two DBAccessor-classes, if they have common logic you can extract it to default methods in an interface or to an abstract class and inherit from it. Then you'll ask Guice to provide different *classes* to the constructors.

Comment: Thanks alfasin, but in this case DBAccessor is provided by a library and can not be modified or extended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your `DbAccessor` class twice, with a different [qualifier annotation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) for each table. Then your classes can each inject the right qualified binding they need.

Comment: Thanks Daniel but let me elaborate a bit more on my approach. DBAccessor class is actually injected in DBService, where Cart and Payment class are injecting different DBServices using binding annotations.